# Do scalar matrices form an open subset?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

Suppose $R$ is a ring with a topology, e.g. $R=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_p$. For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, consider the subring of $M_n(R)$ consisting of all scalar matrices, that is the set of all matrices of the form $rI_n$ for some $r\in R$. Is it true that this subring is open in $M_n(R)$.

If this is not true in general, are there any conditions on $R$ under which it holds (excluding the obvious case where the topology on $R$ is discrete)? In particular, is it true when $R$ is a (possibily non-commutative) discrete valuation ring?

Comment: Hint: Are there matrices with real entries near the scalar matrices but not themselves scalar matrices? In more generality, are there ring elements near $0$ that aren't $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n > 1$ and the topology is not discrete, every neighbourhood of $0$ contains something nonzero, and every neighbourhood of I contains ...